# Save array in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

[This is my full code](http://jsfiddle.net/SG4Vh/)

I need to save the array visited to local storage. Then, I need an if statement to check if the array has been stored. If it has, it will do

```
return;
```

ending the code and making the button not functional. 
Something like this;

```
if (store.length == 3) {
    document.getElementById('btn').className = 'maxques';
    alert('You have completed this category');
    console.log(store);
    return; }
```

I just somehow need to store the array. I tried JSON stringify followed by JSON parse but either they don't work or I'm doing them wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the examples on here for how to use localStorage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of repeating @Tom Hart, use a combination of the functions localstorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem.  Respectively params being key, value and key.

Answer (score 0):

To store your array:

```
localStorage.userEdits=array.join(","); //or another delimiter
```

To check if stored:

```
if(localStorage.userEdits){
    //stored!
}
```